# BigQuery Monthly Active Users?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm currently working off a query from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662296/moving-n-day-active-users-bigquery). That query is written in Legacy SQL and will not work in my environment. I've modified the query to use the modern SQL functions and updated the `SELECT date as date` to use `timestamp_micros`.

I should also mention that the rows I'm trying to select are coming in from Firebase Analytics.

My Query:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) as date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN users END) as days_07,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 14 THEN users END) as days_14,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30 THEN users END) as days_30
FROM (
    SELECT
        FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) as date,
        periods.period as period,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as users
    FROM `com_sidearm_fanapp_uiowa_IOS.*` as activity
    CROSS JOIN
        UNNEST(event_dim) as event  
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)) as date
        FROM `com_sidearm_fanapp_uiowa_IOS.*`
        CROSS JOIN
            UNNEST(event_dim) as event 
        GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros
    ) as dates
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            period 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 7 as period 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 14 as period 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 30 as period
            )
    ) as periods
    WHERE 
        dates.date >= activity.date 
    AND 
        SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dates.date, activity.date, DAY)/periods.period) AS INT64) = 0
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
CROSS JOIN 
    UNNEST(event_dim) as event
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: For others visiting this post, the BQ export schema is defined [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Column name period is ambiguous at [24:13] error.

to fix this particular error - you should fix below

```
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            period 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 7 as period), 
            (SELECT 14 as period), 
            (SELECT 30 as period)
    ) as periods
```

so it should look like:

```
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            period 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 7 as period UNION ALL
            SELECT 14 as period UNION ALL
            SELECT 30 as period)
    ) as periods
```

> Answer on your updated question

Try below. I didn't have chance to test it but hope it can help you fix your query

```
SELECT 
    date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN users END) as days_07,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 14 THEN users END) as days_14,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30 THEN users END) as days_30
FROM (
    SELECT 
        activity.date as date,
        periods.period as period,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user) as users
    FROM (
      SELECT
          event.timestamp_micros as date, 
           user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id as user
      FROM `yourTable` CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) as event  
    ) as activity
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            event.timestamp_micros  as date
        FROM `yourTable` CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) as event 
        GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros
    ) as dates
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT period 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 7 as period UNION ALL 
            SELECT 14 as period UNION ALL
            SELECT 30 as period)
    ) as periods
    WHERE dates.date >= activity.date 
    AND SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(dates.date), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(activity.date), DAY)/periods.period) AS INT64) = 0
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: This is working but now it's throwing another error: `Name date not found inside activity at [31:32]`

Comment: as you mentioned in your question - original query was written for different table which has `date` field in it. so you need to make sure you are using filed that exists in your table

Comment: The fields I'm querying do exist in my table. I'm certain of this. I have changed `date` to `timestamp_micros`

Comment: See updated question please. I event changed the format of the `date` field to match what was in the original legacy SQL query.

Comment: @JoeScotto - this is not how SO is working  - if you have new question you should post it as a NEW question. instead you constantly changing existing question, thus totally invalidating answer(s) on your original question! as an exception (for myself) i will answer one more time - but in future  - I will not answer such never ending all-in-one questions. And by the way - usually title of your question should not be a project or Task Name you are working on  - but rather clear brief and specific issue you have. I know it is not always simple  - but this is how SO works

Comment: You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Seems to be working but running into resource limits. Tier 20 required. Thanks.